# how to create double entry book keeping for member purchases, fees, charges

Tags: mysql

My application records member fees, purchases, overdue charges and payments.

I have read many articles that suggest the use of double entry accounting.

Currently here's my table and I want to convert it to double entry or better database schema.

```
MembersAccount(id, name, address)
Purchases(member_id, amount, product_id, date)
Fees(member_id, amount, fee_type, date)

PurchasePayments(purchase_id, amount, date)
FeePayments(fee_id, amount, date)
```

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Double entry accounting is a specialist skill by itself. To do this properly you'll likely need the assistance of someone trained in accountancy.

The basic principal is that every bit of money is associated with an account. Choosing what accounts and how they relate to each other is where the expertise lies. Money only ever moves between accounts via matching transactions - one to debit the source and the other to credit the destination.